# React: I want to submit a form and want to save data in redux store through hooks (useSelector and useDispatch)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, store

React: I want to submit a form and want to save data in redux store through hooks (useSelector and useDispatch)
Let me know if an thing else required I will upload 
I need this help on this issue
i will be thankfull

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {
  Button,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
  Container,
  Col
} from "reactstrap";
import "./style.scss";

import { addUserAction } from "../../store/reducers/registerReducer.js";

const Register = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const usedispatch = useDispatch();
  const addUser = user => usedispatch(addUserAction(user));

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(user);
    if (user.trim() === "") return;
    addUser(user);
  };
  const onChange = e => {
    //console.log(e.target.value);
    setUser(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Container className="register">
      <h2>Register</h2>
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler} className="form">
        <Col>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label>Full Name</Label>
            <Input
              type="text"
              name="fullname"
              id="fullname"
              value={user.fullname}
              placeholder="Full Name"
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </Col>

        <Col>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label>Email</Label>
            <Input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              value={user.email}
              id="email"
              placeholder="myemail@email.com"
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="examplePassword">Password</Label>
            <Input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={user.password}
              id="password"
              placeholder="********"
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </Col>
        <Button>Submit</Button>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Register;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// reducer
const initialState = {
  fullname: "",
  email: "",
  password: ""
};

function userRegister(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_USER":
      return {
        ...state
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default userRegister;

// Actions
export const addUserAction = user => ({
  type: "ADD_USER",
  payload: user
});
```

React: I want to submit a form and want to save data in redux store through hooks (useSelector and useDispatch)
Let me know if an thing else required I will upload 
I need this help on this issue
i will be thankfull

Answer (score 2):

Your `user` state is a string and gets updated as a string. But you are accessing it as an object `user.fullname`.

Second, you are submitting your redux action with an empty user object and not the form values:

```js
addUser({
  fullname: "",
  email: "",
  password: ""
});
```

Either change your form to use different `useState`'s for each value, or better yet change the current `user` state to be an object. Then send that object instead:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState({
  fullname: "",
  email: "",
  password: ""
});

const onChange = e => {
  setUser({...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
};

addUser(user);
```

Last, you aren't using the payload in your reducer, just returning state. Save the user by returning it like this:

```js
case "ADD_USER":
  return action.payload;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={user.email}
          id="email"
          placeholder="myemail@email.com"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
```

what i should put here in value